# MySQL replication while disconnect from cluster

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, replication

I'm looking for a solution to replicate MySQL database. I have 3 servers in 3 different locations. **Data have to replicate each other**.

The first idea was to use build-in MySQL replication mechanism but it doesn't support multi-master.

Next I was testing Galera cluster, which almost fits my expectations, but I need a solution which allows to work on the database even if the server doesn't have  connection with the cluster.

Do you know any solution for MySQL which:

- support multi-master,
- allows to work on the database while
  disconnecting,
- when connection backs, the changes will be merged.

Comment: try this article in MySQL documentation - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html

Comment: @JosMac unfortunatelly testing using build-in MySQL replication mechanism occurs big problems while loosing connection with other servers - server stops from replicating.

Comment: Yes, I know this problem - most common are problems with network connectivity - please read this - http://mysql.freeideas.cz/subdom/mysql/2016/08/16/mysql-replication-troubleshooting-lags-on-replicas/ - you can tune several settings to lower delays in case of lost connectivity. Text is for 5.5. On 5.7 there is additional setting in CHANGE MASTER TO command - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/change-master-to.html - master connect retry

Comment: @JosMac, thank you for your replies. I have another question, do you know any good way to handle problem with primary key indexes? Let's say the disconnected server will insert some rows, and at the same time other server inserted some rows too. Indexes overlap each other. How to handle that problem when connection will be back and the databases will try to replicate? The only solution is to set auto_increment_increment?

Comment: That's a really good question and I must admit we were unable to find solution robust enough. Both parameters "auto_increment_increment" and "auto_increment_offset" just reserve intervals of values. That's all. Maybe "group_replication_auto_increment_increment" can help more but we decided to implement strict tree structure with one master only. It was easier for us and logically the cleanest solution. So - I am sorry, I do not know the answer for this.